# Default roles aren't taking

Tags: bjyauthorize

```
'default_role'       => 'guest',
'authenticated_role' => 'user',
'identity_provider'  => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider',
```

I have the previous default roles defined and Developer Tools shows that they're taking, however, Developer Tools is showing my logged in authentication (for a User which does not have a role defined) to be undefined. Shouldn't the default become user, unless I choose to overwrite it?

So confused by this module. Maybe it's because I'm also using Mongo ODM with it.

Edit:
I've figured out how to add the default role that I want via a hook into ZfcUser registration, but I still feel like I shouldn't **need** to do that.